# iPhone 3GS iOS 5 support (nibs to storyboards)

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard, nib, iphone-3gs

I have an iOS project that supports iPhone 3GS and on and requires iOS 5 or later.
This project is using nibs instead of storyboards and is using ivars and properties the "old" way (i.e declaring ivars and the appropriate properties).

I would like to work hard and convert this project to a "new" way, i.e to storyboards and clean up the redundant ivars and the synthesise things). It does use ARC, though.

My question is first: will I still be able to support iPhone 3GS?
And second, is there any convenient way to transform this project to the new-fashioned way besides just manually copying the nibs to storyboards and managing all the IBOutlets and IBActions and so on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**will I still be able to support iPhone 3GS?     NO**

[Apple doc clearly says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html)

> Storyboards are supported in iOS 5 and later and are enabled by default for new projects. If your app must run on earlier versions of iOS, though, you cannot use storyboards and should continue to use nib files

**Is there any convenient way to transform?**

There is no shortcut(single step)to convert an existing application to use storyboards.
[Converting to Storyboards](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/index.html)

Comment: I want to support iPhone 3GS running iOS 5 and later.